# Quest 2 Gardian Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, quest

I use to disable guardian in my phisical vr escape room to let the players moove without limits.

From 1 week i think, with guardian disabled in developer hub and in the quest, i see the players drifting, all the objects moove a little bit, loosing initial position.

i tryed disabling it with meta developer hub and sidequest too

How can i solve this? this problem is detrying the user experience
i don't know what to try anymore

until a week ago there was no such problem...

Comment: Just to understand .. you have a room of unlimited size so you don't have to worry about anyone running into a wall? ^^ In general any inside out tracking is kinda inaccurate in a big more or less empty room .. try to add enough key points the system can track so it doesn't loose it's position that easy .. since it is VR you can obfuscate those trackers anyway and users won't see them ... But the Quest can and improve tracking

Comment: @derHugo exactly, my software places all 3d object matching room size and the position was perfect, even for hours. But now idk why, it sucks from 2 weeks

Comment: I don't know too much about the quest .. but on Hololens we completely deleted all room tracking once in a while to reset and rescan the room when hitting this kind of issues